# Convert Castle Windsor xml config to C# code

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I want to convert something like this:

```
<components>
    <component id=""service1"" service=""WindsorTests.IService, MyAssembly""         type=""WindsorTests.Service1, MyAssembly""/>
    <component id=""service2"" service=""WindsorTests.IService, MyAssembly"" type=""WindsorTests.Service2, MyAssembly""/>
    <component id=""consumer"" type=""WindsorTests.Consumer, MyAssembly"">
        <parameters>
            <services>
                <dictionary>
                    <entry key=""one"">${service1}</entry>
                    <entry key=""two"">${service2}</entry>
                </dictionary>
            </services>
        </parameters>
    </component>
</components>
```

Into code like this:

```
Container.AddComponentWithProperties<Consumer>(Container.ResolveAll<IService>());
```

Anyone have any ideas how to do this.

**Note:**

I am trying to do something like what is described in this post, but without using XML:
[Windsor Castle :- Inject Dictionary of Interfaces via configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890287/windsor-castle-inject-dictionary-of-interfaces-via-configuration)

Comment: What does Consumer look like? I'm not quite sure I understand whether the services you would like to inject are a list, a params array, a dictionary or something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
container.Register(Component.For<Consumer>()
               .DynamicParameters((kernel, parameters) => 
                   parameters["services"] = new Dictionary<string, IService> {
                     {"one", kernel.Resolve<IService>("service1")},
                     {"two", kernel.Resolve<IService>("service2")},
                   }
               ));
```

See the [fluent API wiki](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API) for reference.

Comment: Worked great, I needed to upgrade to the newest version of Castle Windsor for this to work (DynamicParameters was not in the version I had).

Comment: In addition, the fluent API version of the 'normal' register is:

Container.Register(Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy< WindsorTests.Service1 >().Named("service1"));